# Convert Base64 to Image and then display it

Tags: android, image, base64

I've got a base64 string in my db (yes i know its bad practice) and i want to convert so I can do  `ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.MyConvertedImage);`.I found the bottom lines on here but not entirely sure what they are doing,  I think i'm close but unsure how to progress past this:

```
 public void getTorsoFromDb(String Email){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Head FROM Avatar WHERE Email=?", new String[]{Email});
    if(cursor.moveToLast()){
        Head64String = cursor.getString(0);
    }

    String imageDataBytes = Head64String.substring(Head64String.indexOf(",")+1);
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(imageDataBytes.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));


}
```

So what i need help on is getting from a base64, to a viewable image file. Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: You can never use setImageResource as you cannot put a picture in drawable at runtime.

Comment: Of course you can convert base64 string to an image and then load that image from stream or file. But not from resource.

Comment: Make a Bitmap first from your stream and then set the bitmap to the image view.

Comment: How does one do this? I'm a bit of a noob

Comment: Google for BitmapFactory.decodeStream().

Comment: this is all so confusing, so im doing BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)?

Comment: So would this be right ?  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
        IV2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Head);
        IV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);