# ''android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission() while accessing image from downloads folder

Tags: android, storage, file-permissions

I am trying to load images from the Downloads folder to an imageView and then upload it using retrofit. But, I am getting `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/124 from pid=24654, uid=10177 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()`. I have tried loading images from different folders and they worked fine. I was getting NullPonterException initially and found that I had to replace **content://downloads/public_downloads** with **content://downloads/all_downloads** and Now I am getting this error.  Here are the codes I have tried so far :

**Thanks in Advance**

**FileUtils.java**

```
public class FileUtils {
    String getPathFromUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        String path = getPathFromLocalUri(context, uri);
        if (path == null) {
            path = getPathFromRemoteUri(context, uri);
        }
        return path;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getPathFromLocalUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                Log.d("isDownload", "Yes");
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                    try {
                        final Uri contentUri =
                                ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/all_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {split[1]};

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String getDataColumn(
            Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;

        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String getPathFromRemoteUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        // The code below is why Java now has try-with-resources and the Files utility.
        File file = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            file = File.createTempFile("image_picker", "jpg", context.getCacheDir());
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                copy(inputStream, outputStream);
                success = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
            try {
                if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
                // If closing the output stream fails, we cannot be sure that the
                // target file was written in full. Flushing the stream merely moves
                // the bytes into the OS, not necessarily to the file.
                success = false;
            }
        }
        return success ? file.getPath() : null;
    }

    private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        out.flush();
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

**pickImage method:**

```
 //Gallery
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void openGallery() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_CODE);
        }

    }
```

**manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
.......

 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>

</application>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Do away with all those terrible get path from ... functions. If you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT you need two lines of code in onActivityResult to put the selected image in an image view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120448/convert-base64-to-image-and-then-display-it?noredirect=1#comment104471023_59120448

Comment: Sorry, i have missed a key point there. I also want to upload the image using retrofit. I have edited my question.

Comment: The best approach here is to avoid to use the `File` class at all. Because now that Android is more strict on file handling you should use `DocumentFile` and `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri)` and work with this object instead